# JavaDoc to (Doku)Wiki conversion / doclet

Tags: api, documentation, wiki, javadoc, dokuwiki

Our company has a very large public Java API which is currently being released standalone and online using (of course) JavaDoc. It is surrounded by product documentation which links into the API.

We are moving our static documentation to DokuWiki - which works pretty good - and want to  keep the links.

Now it would be good to have a method (or doclet) that exports the JavaDoc directly into DokuWiki - or a very near alternative.

Question: Is there something like this or do you know a method to do just that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Doclet which writes to JSON.

https://bitbucket.org/ananelson/json-doclet/src/tip/src/it/dexy/jsondoclet/Doclet.java

It might help get you started writing a custom Doclet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write doclet yourself, its not hard - its just html generation from very nice meta-model.

[this might help](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/overview.html)

P.S. doclet api is in lib/tools.jar of your sdk.

Comment: I thought so … I just hoped someone had already done that … :)

Comment: doclets are really dead, many people realize that you dont really need that documentation when you have the code.